# select multible comumns with notna property

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

let's say that I have the following dataset where `colunn1`, `column2` have all their values opposite to `column3`, `column4`

```
 column1 column2, column3, column 4
0 aaa     bbb       NAN     NAN
1 aaa     bbb       ccc     NAN
2 aaa     bbb       ccc     NAN
3 aaa     bbb       NAN     NAN
4 aaa     bbb       ccc     DDD
5 aaa     bbb       NAN     NAN
6 aaa     bbb       NAN     DDD
7 aaa     bbb       ccc     DDD
8 aaa     bbb       NAN     DDD
```

I want to select all the rows that have values. In the  beginning, I use the following one

```
df = df[df["column3"] .notna()]
```

what I want is to retain the rows that have values regarding if their not exists value in another column

so the above data frame can be

```
 column1 column2, column3, column 4
0 
1 aaa     bbb       ccc     NAN
2 aaa     bbb       ccc     NAN
3 
4 aaa     bbb       ccc     DDD
5 
6 aaa     bbb       NAN     DDD
7 aaa     bbb       ccc     DDD
8 aaa     bbb       NAN     DDD
```

How to achieve the above objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `NAN` is a `np.nan` , you can use a mask with all on axis=1:

```
out = df.mask(df[['column3','column4']].isna().all(1))
```

---

```
print(out) 

  column1 column2 column3 column4
0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1     aaa     bbb     ccc     NaN
2     aaa     bbb     ccc     NaN
3     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4     aaa     bbb     ccc     DDD
5     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
6     aaa     bbb     NaN     DDD
7     aaa     bbb     ccc     DDD
8     aaa     bbb     NaN     DDD
```

Comment: how to delete the columns that have only nan values?

Answer (score 1):

Also assuming NaN is `np.nan`.

Another option is [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) to fill rows with value:

```
df.loc[df[['column3', 'column4']].isnull().all(axis=1)] = ''
```

`df`:

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4
0                                
1     aaa     bbb     ccc     NaN
2     aaa     bbb     ccc     NaN
3                                
4     aaa     bbb     ccc     DDD
5                                
6     aaa     bbb     NaN     DDD
7     aaa     bbb     ccc     DDD
8     aaa     bbb     NaN     DDD
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa'],
    'column2': ['bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb'],
    'column3': [np.nan, 'ccc', 'ccc', np.nan, 'ccc', np.nan, np.nan, 'ccc',
                np.nan],
    'column4': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'DDD', np.nan, 'DDD', 'DDD',
                'DDD']
})

df.loc[df[['column3', 'column4']].isnull().all(axis=1)] = ''
print(df)
```